# Box Select polygons, only visible? No other options?

Tags: modeling

Edit Mode -  Drag and Select Polygons

[image]

So why aren't ALL the polys within the bounds selected?

[image]

Where is the option to enable this common, very useful function?

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be in <kbd>x-ray</kbd> mode using <kbd>Alt-Z</kbd> to box select all the faces within the area bounded by the selection box.

Comment: Why only in X Ray View? That doesn't make any sense. 

Even in XRV any polygons I touch with the selection area will not be selected until the area covers the center dot for each polygon. 

Who designs a tool like this? 

Why are there no options for tolerant selection of polygons, a very common basic function found in other 3D programs, but not Blender for some reason?

What could possibly be the reasoning behind limiting select all polys to only XRV? Shouldn't users be able to decide for themselves? Where are the tool options for that?

Thanks.

Comment: That's the way it's always been in Blender and the way it will stay. You'll just have to learn to live with it!